# When should I use "glanced at" or "glanced to"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> With ant-sized steps, glancing a couple of times **to/at** Aida, Fumiko
>   walked toward Takashima until she stood right on his left.

Should it be to or at. I ask, because I've seen both cases.

Comment: Glanced to the direction, glanced at the person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**at** is very much more common than **toward** which is slightly more common than **to**.  [See this NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glanced%20to%2C%20glanced%20at%2C%20glanced%20toward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cglanced%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglanced%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglanced%20toward%3B%2Cc0)

The only occasion when **at** is not permissible is when you specify a direction (to the north, to the left).